# Webpack scss extension Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I work on an angular2 app using webpack as a compiler,

my webpack.config

```js
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app/main.ts',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loaders: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

my webpack.config.dev

```js
var path = require('path');

var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', options: {
                        transpileOnly: true
                    }},
                    { loader: 'angular2-template-loader' },
                    { loader: 'angular-router-loader' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

and my webpack.config.prod

```js
var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
 
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
   entry: './src/app/main.aot.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'},
                    { loader: 'angular2-template-loader' },
                    { loader: 'angular-router-loader?aot=true' }
                ]
            },
           {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass?")
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        extractSass
    ],
    postcss: [
        Autoprefixer
    ]
});
```

here is my npm build process

```js
 "build": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080 --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build:prod": "del-cli dist && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'src/app/**/*.js' 'src/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'src/app/**/*.js.map' 'src/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'src/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'src/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts' 'dist/app'"
```

The issue is that when I run npm run build everythings is working fine, but if I run npm run build:prod, it return an error, actually it cannot access to my scss files

example I have in my general.scss

```css
@import 'colour-palette';
```

so it return the error

```js
Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found  D:/git/path/path-path/front/src/app/shared/scss/colour-palette
```

I ve tried a lot of thing but it doesn t work, if someone have a solution I ll be more than happy

Comment: Did you find any resolution to this ?

Comment: Hey did u find the answer for this?

Comment: Hi Guys I could find the right answer . sorry about that. it was easier for me to use angular-cli and

ng new My_New_Project --style=sass
or 
ng new My_New_Project --style=scss

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
{
 test: /\.scss$/,
 loader:ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass?")
 }
```

With

```
{
 test: /\.scss$/,
 loader:extractSass.extract("style", "css!sass?")
 }
```